# How to pass a parameter from javascript to a UserControl?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, user-controls

In my ASP.Net application, there's a UserControl called `EmployeesUserControl` which is shown through a JQuery modal dialog.

Before showing the Employees, I've got to pass a filter criteria which is the entity that the employee is belong to. **My question is that how can I pass the value from javascript to the UserControl**?

---

What I tried so far is that I created a HiddenControl called `SelectedEntityHiddenControl` and I set it a value  before showing the popup, hence, when the popup is shown and the `Page_Load` event handler of the UserControl is called, then I read the value of the hidden control and filter by it. But I don't think it's a good implementation what I've already done.

Any suggestion!

Comment: http://aspxtutorial.com/post/2011/01/02/Load-aspnet-web-user-control-using-jQuery-and-web-method.aspx

Comment: I fully agree with DSW - will be better pass filter params and get result by one ajax-call. Mainstream is AJAX!!! In these cases I often use AjaxPro-library - its really simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a good solution. I'm also using HiddenFields to pass values from JS to the ASP.NET Engine and back.

You've to ensure that your values are passed to the asp.net engine at the correct moment within the lifecycle.